# Undo Git Pull without losing untracked files?

Tags: git, git-pull

I have a feature branch called `testing_automation` that I haven't committed in over a week. I have a lot of new, untracked files in the branch. I went to go to `develop` branch to check a different task but messed it up.
I will list what I did in order:

(Current Branch 'feature/testing_automation'):

1. git stash
2. git checkout . (undo any locally compiled npm files)
3. meant to run `git checkout develop` but ran `git pull develop`

Now I have conflicts since it pulled develop in but I also don't want fix them because when I go to run `git stash apply` , there will be conflicts again. How can I undo the `git pull develop` from my feature branch without losing the untracked files. I have all the tracked files in `git stash` so I am not worried about losing those -- I can just apply those.

Comment: git stash shouldn't touch your untracked files, did you mean you ran `git stash -u`?

Comment: no, only ran git stash

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First I advise you to backup your entire project directory before doing anything.

`git merge --abort` should stop the pull's merge conflict resolution and bring things to how they were.

(Remember that a `pull` is simply `git fetch` followed by `git merge` - That's the reason we `--abort` a `merge` and not a `pull`. The `merge` part is the part that caused those conflicts)

Comment: worked!  that is exactly what I needed and thank you for explaining what goes on behind the scenes of a `pull`.  Thanks!

Comment: @timmyLtus please do not forget to accept this answer ;)